# Update MKMapView when app is in background

Tags: ios, background, mkmapview, cllocationmanager

I have code in my iOS app that uses `MKMapView` to run certain code when the user moves:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView
            didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    // The code I want to run
}
```

I was wondering if it was possible to keep updating even if the app was in the background, or if not, how to replicate this code in `CLLocationManager`.

**EDIT:**
I need this code to get the position of the user in the background

Comment: Have you looked at the location manager methods and callbacks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was wondering if it was possible to keep updating even if the app was in the background, or if not, how to replicate this code in CLLocationManager.

There's no point in updating a map view if the view isn't being displayed on the screen.

If you want to do something even when the map view isn't visible, you *should* use Core Location. All you need to do is to create an instance of `CLLocationManager`, give it a delegate, and tell it to start updating. Your location manager delegate can implement `-locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` to get location updates, and you can do whatever you like with the updated information.

Note that you shouldn't unnecessarily use location when the app is in the background. Read more about getting updates in the background in [Getting Location Updates in the Background](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW10).

Comment: Thank you. That makes so much more sense